# Apache Camel Grace Period Pattern

Tags: apache-camel, spring-camel

I'm using Apache Camel and I need to ingest 'requests' in order to perform some actions asynchronously. I do so by using the REST component and putting the requests in a queue (ActiveMQ). However, within the next 'x' minutes, I might receive a message that makes the former request obsolete. I need a kind of grace period in which the first request might be removed before it is processed.

How can I implement this in Camel?

B.t.w.: I expected an high load (number of messages)

Comment: Do you have an upper limit of how long the cancellation might take? If you do have an upper limit say 5 minutes just set the JMS delivery time to now + 5 min.

Comment: And is there a way to remove that request from the queue if the removal action occurs before the timeout?

Comment: Add removal requests to a claim check pattern. Everytime you read a message from queue check if claim check has a corresponding cancel message.